# Augmented Matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

For which real numbers $ a$ and $b$ does the following linear system have 
(a) no solution,
(b) exactly one solution, or 
(c) infinitely many solutions? Justify your answers.

$$ (a-1)x + (a+3)y + z = 1 $$

$$ax + a^2y + z = 1$$

$$x + ay + z  = b$$

i start by putting it as an augmented matrix, but then i dont know how to reduce it into row echelon form or reduced ref. because of the algebraic terms. is there anyone that can help? thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}(a-1)x + (a+3)y + z = 1 \\
ax + a^2y + z = 1 \\
x + ay + z = b\end{cases} \iff \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} a-1 & a+3 & 1 & 1 \\ a & a^2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a & 1 & b \end{array}\right]$$

OK, now we just do Gauss-Jordan:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} a-1 & a+3 & 1 & 1 \\ a & a^2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a & 1 & b \end{array}\right] \sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & b \\ a & a^2 & 1 & 1 \\ a-1 & a+3 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]\\ \sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1-a & 1-ab \\ 0 & a+3-(a^2-a) & 1-(a-1) & 1-b(a-1) \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & -a+1 & -ab+1 \\ 0 & -a^2 + 2a+3 & -a+2 & -ab+b+1 \end{array}\right] \\ \sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & b \\ 0 & -a^2 + 2a+3 & -a+2 & -ab+b+1 \\ 0 & 0 & -a+1 & -ab+1 \end{array}\right] \\ \sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{a-2}{(a+1)(a-3)} & \frac{ab-b-1}{(a+1)(a-3)} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{ab-1}{a-1} \end{array}\right]$$

Be sure to keep track of anything you divide by -- for instance I divided by $-a^2+2a+3=-(a+1)(a-3)$ in the second row of the last step and $-a+1$ in the last row of the last step.  So you'll need to try $a=-1$, $a=3$, and $a=1$ individually.

Does that help?

Comment: shouldnt u minus the one away for the top row? row 1 - row 3? or its not needed

Comment: You don't really need to go any further than row eschelon form (as in you don't need to get all the way to *reduced* row eschelon form) to figure out if the system has 0, 1, or infinitely many solutions.  So, you *can*, but it's just extra work.

Comment: sigh im stuck with this question, i dont even know how to continue even after i get the ref.. :(

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $b$ are such that we didn't divide by $0$ at any point in the above steps.  Then how many solutions does the system have given we were able to get it into a form with $1$'s all along the primary diagonal and all $0$'s below that diagonal?

Comment: if we leave it at -a+1 for the last row can we solve for no solution? -a+1 = 0

Comment: then the right hand side is non zero

Comment: ab is not equal to 1, thus a is 1 while b is all real numbers except 1 when there is no solution?

Comment: Yes.  Then to find when there are infinitely many solutions just find when $-a+1=0$ AND $-ab+1=0$.  You'll also need to set up the same types of equations for the second row.  That is where the left equals $0$ and the right is non-zero and when both are zero.